ray failed to init on win11 in python 3.9 and raise a TimeoutError
Python 3.9.19 (main, Mar 21 2024, 17:21:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
ray.__version__: '2.10.0'
platform:Win11
When I init ray as follows:
import ray
ray.init()

it raise an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File D:\software\anaconda\envs\TradeMaster\lib\site-packages\ray\_private\node.py:318 in __init__
    ray._private.services.wait_for_node(

  File D:\software\anaconda\envs\TradeMaster\lib\site-packages\ray\_private\services.py:464 in wait_for_node
    raise TimeoutError(

TimeoutError: Timed out after 60 seconds while waiting for node to startup. Did not find socket name tcp://127.0.0.1:48150 in the list of object store socket names.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[3], line 1
    ray.init()

  File D:\software\anaconda\envs\TradeMaster\lib\site-packages\ray\_private\client_mode_hook.py:103 in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File D:\software\anaconda\envs\TradeMaster\lib\site-packages\ray\_private\worker.py:1645 in init
    _global_node = ray._private.node.Node(

  File D:\software\anaconda\envs\TradeMaster\lib\site-packages\ray\_private\node.py:323 in __init__
    raise Exception(

Exception: The current node timed out during startup. This could happen because some of the Ray processes failed to startup.

Could anyone help?
I have read a lot docs, but seems a little people comes up with the same problem.

Looks like there's nothing on localhost accepting connections on port 48150
